# Contact Form 7 How to Alter the From email address?

Tags: email, plugin-contact-form-7

In the past we were able to put a user email address in the From field. But now we get the message: " this email address does not belong to the same domain as". 
I know you should use ie. noreply@mydomain.com

Because of an internal develop emailprogram I need to have the user email address in the From field. The internal develop email program has some features which depends on the From field in a email message.

Is there a way i can trick CF7 so it use the / overwrites the "this email address does not belong to the same domain" warning? Jus like < CF 3.1

Hope you get my question

Comment: Why does the warning bother you? As far as I know CF7 will still try to send out the mails, it is just a warning after all

Comment: @kero, ......that would be something.....going to see if it still works.....tx for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

You can trick CF7 by enter a valid email address `noreply@mydomain.com` and redirect all mails to that custom email address `some@otherdomain.com`.

;-)

In the end that warning should not harm.

It's more a Spam issue:
If the recipient of the email rates the email as spam because it comes from a different server than the sender's address says.

Comment: tx for your input. The recipient is our own server, we just use a CRM which uses the From field to arrange customer cards

Comment: if your own server is fine with that custom email address. it will work. the warning is targeting email sending to the public, i would say.